Visibility of Planetary alignment of 6 planets on 3 June 2024 from Prague
I have just found out about the alignment of Mercury, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, and Neptune on 2024-06-03 and I'd like to see if it is possible to watch the event from the vicinity of Prague, but have no idea how to find out.
Where can I find out, if and possibly when the event can be seen from Prague (or its vicinity)?

You can use any planetarium software to see what they sky will look like from your location.  E.g. a good one for desktop use is https://stellarium.org/

Since you're asking about Prague, have you checked whether or not the Stefanik observatory on Petřín hill will be doing anything to mark the occasion? I don't have any idea how to check whether or not they are, but it's publicly accessible and they may have the kit available to filter out the sun and see the alignment. Just a thought...

Not in a meaningful way.
Saturn will be visible and a bright object in the morning sky. Mars should be visible, but by the time it rises, twilight will have started. Jupiter and Mercury are only a few degrees from the sun and invisible in the sun's glare (from anywhere on Earth) Venus is behind the sun.  Uranus is close to Mercury and Jupiter in the sky and lost in the glare.  Neptune is visible, between Mars and Saturn, but at 8th magnitude, it will require a telescope to see.
The planets are not exactly aligned, but are in the same general region of the sky.  However that region is near the sun in the sky, so most of the planets are not visible from anywhere on Earth.
The planets move pretty slowly,  you can see more or less the same arrangement right now.  Your post suggests that you think this is a "one night event". It's not. It is (to the naked eye) two planets in the same general region of the sky in the morning.  Actually perhaps more interesting is the sky in the evening, when there are no planets visible at all. It's relatively unusual for the sky to have no planets!  Also, since the planets move slowly, alignments are generally equally visible from anywhere on Earth. You don't have to be in a particular place.  This is because the planets are far away.  Compare with solar eclipses, which are only visible in a narrow strip.

James K is correct, but I would like to add some details on the "where can I find out" part of the question.
If you are ever interested in what objects (stars, sun, moon, planets, satellites, nebulae, etc.) are visible at a given location & time, the software/app to use is Stellarium. It's free, open-source, easy use and runs on pretty much everything.
After selecting time & location, just switch on labels for planets and find that Venus, Jupiter & Mercury are all close to the sun and therefore under the horizon for most of the night. Switching the obstruction by the ground on and off makes it clear that these objects are below the horizon:

It can be a really useful tool to have for everyone with the slightest interest in astronomy. If it's only planets you care about, there are some other websites that can quickly tell which ones are above the horizon after sunset, such as meteoblue.

Thanks, this will certainly be useful for planning nightly trips in the near future :)
